# View, Create and update comments in VFP

Tags: visualforce, chatter

Can anyone tell me how to view, create  and update comments in chatter using Visualforce page?

Give some example.
Thanks in advance
Karthick

Comment: Karthick, that's a broad question which doesn't show you've done much effort of your own. What's the true question here, accessing this data from apex, whether they are standardControllers for them in Visualforce or how to show the data you already have in a controller in Visualforce ?  Try to ask specific questions which are focused on a single issue, not covering an entire solution of feature you're trying to develop.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke : I wanna add and delete the comments in Chatter using Visualforce ..for that what i have to do?

Comment: Try breaking apart your question in to parts you know or not know, and try to deal with them individually rather than asking for them al combined.  Often when searching for the individual parts of a problem, you'll be able to solve it by yourself and learn how to use these technologies better.